# What is checkbox.log and why is it 8 GB large?

Tags: storage, checkbox

Using the program Baobab, I spotted that I had a file that was gigantic: `~/.cache/checkbox/checkbox.log`, 8 GB large. In the same folder, I have also a 360 MB large file called `subunit.log`.

What is it? Why is it so large? Can I remove it or reduce its size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkbox is a program to run automatic hardware tests and report problems. It is called "System Test" in the unity dash / applications menu. You must have run it at some point. This file contains the log of the process, which appears to include a lot of details in your case. This file, and anything inside `~/.cache` for that matter, can be safely deleted.

Comment: OK I am just going to delete the .checkbox folder entirely then.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete it, for it will be recreated automatically, starting pilling up data from start. There is already a bug report about it on launchpad about its default size limit.

You may also change the log level to error only, which will reduce the frequency of writes.

```
checkbox-gtk -W /usr/share/checkbox/data/whitelists/default.whitelist --log-level=error
```

Comment: I cannot find the bug report. Could you please link to it in your answer?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/checkbox/+bug/877810